# Convert Name of day to number -e.g- Monday to 1

Tags: amazon-redshift

I don't have timestamp table. I just need to convert using name string,

```
SELECT day_of_week;
```

Output should look like

```
day_of_week sum
Friday       5
Monday       1
Saturday     6
Sunday       7
Thursday     4
Tuesday      2
Wednesday    3
```

Answer (score 1):

If it were **timestamp** then you can use the `isodow`. See [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/functions-datetime.html)

```
isodow
```

The day of the week as **Monday(1)** to **Sunday(7)**

```
SELECT day_of_week, EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-18 20:38:40') as sum FROM your_table;
```

But you don't have that column. So you can use `CASE...WHEN` like below-

```
SELECT day_of_week,
       CASE WHEN day_of_week='Monday' THEN 1
            WHEN day_of_week='Tuesday' THEN 2
            WHEN day_of_week='Wednesday' THEN 3
            WHEN day_of_week='Thursday' THEN 4
            WHEN day_of_week='Friday' THEN 5
            WHEN day_of_week='Saturday' THEN 6
            ELSE 7
       END as sum
    FROM your_table;
```

See doc: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-conditional.html